# Open and automate webpage in specific chrome profile selenium python (MACVentura)

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Attempting to automate webpage in specific chrome profile using selenium in Python. I'm able to open the desired webpage, however it always opens a new blank chrome profile instead of my desired default profile. Chrome 115 has its own automated testing browser and corresponding driver, so not sure if it has something to do with that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Path to the Chrome profile directory
chrome_profile_path = '/Path/to/chrome/profile'

# Create Chrome options and set the profile directory
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + chrome_profile_path)

# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver with the configured options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Open a website
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Have attempted using service variable but did not work